# How could I change the appearance of the HTML view?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, css

Consider the below Angular 2 Template code :

```
<div *ngIf="artist">
    <header class="artist-header">
        <div *ngIf="artist.images.length > 0">
            <img class="artist-thumb img-circle" src="{{artist.images[0].url}}">
        </div>
        <h1>{{artist.name}}</h1>
        <p *ngIf="artist.genres.length > 0">
            Genres : <span *ngFor="let genre of artist.genres">{{genre}}</span>
        </p>
    </header>
    <div class="artist-albums">

        <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let album of albums">
                    <div class="card bg-faded card-body album">
                        <div *ngIf="album.images.length > 0">
                            <img class="album-thumb img-thumbnail" src="{{album.images[0].url}}">
                            <h4>{{album.name}}</h4>
                            <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" routerLink="/album/{{album.id}}">Album Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In spite of applying `class="col-md-3"`, all `div`s are appearing in a new line vertically. Below is the image shown. I want that 3 `div` should appear horizontally in one line. What's need to be changed within the above code?

[image]

Comment: Please click `<>` and produce a [mcve] using for example lorempixel or placeholder

Comment: can you show your full code? If you have like 5 elements with `col-md-3` in a single row, you might be breaking Bootstrap's grid layout. It'd be easier to help if I can see your code.

Comment: I have just added the full code of that component. Could you please check it out now?

Answer (score 3):

If the whole code you posted is looped to display all these images, each of the `col-md-3` is in a seperate `row` div, which creates a linebreak each time. So try to make the loop *inside* that `row` div, only for the `col-md-3` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add the other bootstrap options to the div:

```
col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3
```

Be sure that you do not have any margins or haven't override the default width from bootstrap using "!important" flag.

Try to see the live CSS using "inspect element" option in your browser and try to change the data there so you can figure out what is going on.